# Array.push inside 2nd nested For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why Array.push doesnt work inside Nested For Loop? But it works if I replace 2nd for Loop with forEach

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
    if (strs.length === 1) {
        return strs.join('')
    }

    let reference = strs[0].split('');
    let answer = [];
    let final = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        let check = strs[i].split('')
        for (let x = 0; x < reference.length; x++) {
            if (reference[x] === check[x]) {
                answer.push(check[x]) //WHY THIS WONT WORK?
            } else return
        }
        reference = answer
    }

    console.log(answer)
};

longestCommonPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flight"]);
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Expected Answer ["f", "l"], But my point is why cant Ipush elements inside the Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` is used to exit the function, use `break` to only exit the loop

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  if (strs.length === 1) {
    return strs.join('')
  }

  let reference = strs[0].split('');
  let answer = [];
  let final = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
    let check = strs[i].split('')    
    for(let x = 0 ; x<reference.length ; x++){
      if(reference[x] === check[x]){
        answer.push(check[x]) //WHY THIS WONT WORK?
      }else break
    }
    reference = answer
  }
  
  console.log(answer)
};

longestCommonPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flight"])
```